# Dynamic dataset building in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large dataset that holds constituent information for an investment index. I want to take the large set of data and create a new dataset/table/sheet that matches certain criteria. Typically, I would just filter the index constituent dataset and copy and paste but I need it to be dynamic.

Take the mini 'large dataset' below for example...

[image]

Since the index holdings/CUSIPs can change daily, I want to dynamically create a table based on this table that only includes CUSIPs that are in the Tech sector, have a maturity of 0-3Y, and a credit rating of BB. How would I go about doing this dynamically?

I cannot use VBA because the future users of this workbook are not familiar with coding. I tried using a pivot table to achieve this but it didn't work out (although, I'm terrible with pivot tables so this could very well be the solution). Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `FILTER()` function here:

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, FILTER(A:E,(B:B="Tech")*(C:C="0-3Y")*(D:D="BB"),""), IF(x=0,"",x))
```

---

Also, instead of using the whole ranges, which will slow down the excel working functionality suggest you to convert the range into a `Structured Reference` and then use the following formula as is:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     x, FILTER(IndexConst,
              (IndexConst[SECTOR]="Tech")*
              (IndexConst[MATURITY]="0-3Y")*
              (IndexConst[CREDIT RATING]="BB"),
         ""), 
     IF(x=0,"",x))
```

---

**Note:** I have named the table as `IndexConst` you may need to change as per your suit.

Comment: Wow, this worked great; I had no idea excel had this functionality. Thank you.